# MvcMailer: trying to send email to one static recipient and Email (in model and view as a text input)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Sorry for the SQOTD:

Using MvcMailer. I created a quote system, wherein users inputs determines pricing. Based on user inputs, an email is generated with a quote.  I want to send that e-mail to the "Email" address the user input as well as to myself.

In my Mailer.cs I have

```
mailMessage.To.Add("some-email@example.com");
```

I want that static e-mail so that I can send myself the quote.

But how can I also send the e-mail to the "Email" the user input in the form?

My model has:

```
public string Email { get; set; }
```

My form (view) has:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Bcc` field (recipient will not see the other email):

```
mailMessage.To.Add("some-email@example.com");
mailMessage.Bcc.Add(model.Email);
```

or the `CC` (recipient will see the other email).